# PersistenceSpecification and Enums

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

How does one test enum type properties with PersistenceSpecification. I have it mapped like this

```
 Map(x => x.AccountStatus).Column("Status").CustomSqlType("int").Not.Nullable();
```

and I check it like this

```
 spec.CheckProperty(o => o.AccountStatus, UserStatus.Disabled)
```

but it fails with this message

> NHibernate.HibernateException: Can't
>   Parse 0 as UserStatus

It does not look like it is Fluent's error message, but just saving it using Session works fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking of .CustomSqlType("int") solves the problem